# How google cloud's Cloud Run is difference from sereverless technology how it is scalable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform, devops, serverless

As Google has announced it's new service cloud run on Google cloud platform. Google says this is scalable as serverless technology. How it is different than serverless technology and how it will be scalable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Run is a Serverless offering built on top of [Knative](https://cloud.google.com/knative/) (an open-source serverless platform). It's different from most of the serverless technologies as it doesn't have any programming language limitations (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/developing)).

The scaling on managed Cloud Run (not Cloud Run on GKE) is based on `concurrency`, or a number of concurrent requests that your service can handle simultaneously.

You are also billed only for the time when any request is being processed by the instance. If your instance responds to 100 requests in 10 seconds, you will be billed only for those 10 seconds. (however, you will also be billed for 10 seconds if there is only 1 request running for 10 seconds, so be careful with instance scaling). ([pricing](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing))

This is the first release, so there are still many limitations (like inability to [connect to Cloud SQL which I wrote an article about](https://medium.com/@petomalina/connecting-to-cloud-sql-from-cloud-run-dcff2e20152a)). You can see the full list of supported services [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services)

Comment: Thanks pentomalina for this brief overview. I still can't understand the pricing structure like if my one request is taking 5 sec and I'm sending 100 requests than I have to pay for ( 5 * 100 = 500 vCPU seconds)?

Comment: You always pay for the time that the server runs. So e.g. if you send 100 requests that can all be handled in 3 seconds (concurrently), you pay for these 3 seconds (unlike lambda where you would pay for 100 requests and their cpu usage separately).

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this answer and wanted to correct it: Google's [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) is a reimplementation of the Knative APIs using Google's internal serverless technology (not the Knative OSS implementation).

Google's internal technology has a lot of dependencies on other non-OSS functionality (Stubby, Borg, LOAS, etc), but also has proven multitenancy and scaling capabilities, which meant that we (Google) went with a two-pronged approach -- build the OSS interface and implementation on today's infrastructure while also providing a managed service that would feel closer to Lambda experience. Google also offers Cloud Run on GKE, which *does* run the OSS software, packaged to fit well on GCP. See the **Choose the platform that fits you** section on the [Cloud Run marketing page](https://cloud.google.com/run) for a feature comparison between the two.

The pricing model for Cloud Run is based on instance CPU seconds and RAM usage; you can choose (for both Knative and Cloud Run) how many concurrent requests each container can run -- this determines how many instances will be created to handle the requests. (Note that Lambda basically forces this number to be 1 -- there is no concurrency allowed.)

If you have 100 requests per second, and each takes 3 seconds, then you'll have the following instance counts at different concurrency:

- ConcurrencyCount=1 : 300 instances
- ConcurrencyCount=10 : 30 instances
- ConcurrencyCount=80 : 4 instances (the default)
- ConcurrencyCount=200 : 2 instances
- ConcurrencyCount=300 : 1 instances

You should set ConcurrencyCount based on how many requests your application can handle without degrading latency at once; this will probably take some experimentation. The default works well for applications which mostly fetch data from a database or two and then do a small amount of processing. If you are receiving a video and then transcoding it locally, something like 1 or 2 will make more sense.